# JS - Remove all spaces and insert space three characters from end

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to format postcode entries in a form correctly so that they have a space in the correct location, which is always three characters from the end. E.g.:

AA1 1AA

A1A 1AA

AA11 1AA

A1 1AA

```
const addSpace = (str, fromEnd) => `${str.slice(0, -1 * fromEnd)} ${str.slice(-1 * fromEnd)}`;    
['word', 'longword'].forEach(word => console.log(addSpace(word, 3)));
    var el = document.getElementById('input_1_14');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.value = addSpace(this.value, 3);
});
```

However, if I type a series of characters into the relevant field it is inserting spaces every other character, in addition to one three characters from the end, e.g.:

1 1 1 1 1 1 111

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is becous of the event `onKeyUp`, you place an extra letter and it keeps adding spaces after every event without removing them.

```js
const addSpace = (str, fromEnd) => `${str.slice(0, -1 * fromEnd)} ${str.slice(-1 * fromEnd)}`;     
const removeSpace = (str) => str.replace(/ /g, "");
const editString = (str, fromEnd) => addSpace(removeSpace(str), fromEnd);
['word', 'longword'].forEach(word => console.log(editString(word, 3)));     

var el = document.getElementById('input_1_14');

el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {     
    this.value = editString(this.value, 3); 
});
```

```html
<input type="tex" id="input_1_14">
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the extra spaces every other character, so if I enter a string of 1s I get this:


   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 111


This is the current code:


```const addSpace = (str, fromEnd) => `${str.slice(0, -1 * fromEnd)} ${str.slice(-1 * fromEnd)}`;    
const removeSpace = (str) => str.replace(/ /g, "");
['word', 'longword'].forEach(word => console.log(addSpace(word, 3)));

 var el = document.getElementById('input_1_14');
el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    this.value = addSpace(this.value, 3);
});```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there a way to make this run on form submission or when the user moves to the next field rather than as the user types? I can use a Click event listener, but I actually want the opposite, so only fire when someone clicks out of this field, or perhaps clicks on the Submit button.

Comment: Instead of using ``keyup`` u use ``focusout``

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function addSpace(str,fromEnd) {
    var result ='';
    fromEnd += 1;
    for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        if (i >= str.length - fromEnd) {
            result += str[i]+' ';
        } else if (str[i] == ' '){
            continue;
        } else {
        result += str[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
['word', 'longword'].forEach(word => console.log(addSpace(word, 3)));
    var el = document.getElementById('input_1_14');
    el.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
        this.value = addSpace(this.value, 3);
    });
```

It Is Now Fully Compatible With Your Code Just Replace It With Your Code And It Will Work

Comment: Thank you. How do I work this into my code so that it applies to the ID input_1_14 ?

Comment: I have updated the code for compatibility of your code. Now you just have to replace this js code with your code.